# android camera preview with textview

Tags: android, camera, textview, preview

I have camera preview on my android app but when I add an 'id' to the TextView in the xml then the app no longer runs. Are you not allowed to have a textview with an id? I need this because I would like the text to change on screen while having the camera preview?

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 > 
<SurfaceView   android:id="@+id/camerapreview"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

control.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="120dp" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mind" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="First Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="30dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/takepicture" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Save Image"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java:

```
package com.example.androidcamera;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    TextView textGenerateDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mind);
    textGenerateDesc.setText("hi");

    Button buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback,    myPictureCallback_RAW,
                    myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: added the code. basically, it only works when no id is in the textview..

Comment: As far as i know it should work properly, unless android doesnt like having textviews with IDs on cameras.

Comment: the app doesnt open at all and crashes instantly, the debug crashes on viewroot.draw or something

Comment: try to paste the error here please

Comment: ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1446

Comment: If i remove the textview stuff in the .java and also remove the id in the xml it works...the button can have an id so I dont see why the textview cant?!

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of the problem, but I noticed that you set the id='@+id/textview' in your xml-layout file. However, in onCreate, your retrieving it by the id of R.id.mind. I would expect your id to be equal to id="@+id/mind" if you're retrieving if by R.id.mind.

Comment: ok i edited the question, since thats not the source of the problem :S

Comment: Are you able to step into OnCreate while debugging? or does the crash happen before onCreate gets called? What is the error that LogCat gives you?

Comment: That's strange. I restarted my phone, and now it works. It accepts the id and even changes text.wtf. PROBLEM SOLVERED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I can see in the xml you give the `textview` id as "textview" and in code you take it by `R.id.mind`

Did you changed the code here or its the code that you have?

Comment: Ive already changed that, i just editted it for stackoverflow. in mine they are the same.

Comment: did you tried to do 'viewControl.getChildAt(1)' ? and get out the id :D, it's a little stupid but try it

Comment: That's strange. I restarted my phone, and now it works. It accepts the id and even changes text.wtf.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the starting tag of 'LinearLayout'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

rest are same

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="120dp"
 />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/mind"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:text="First Text"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/takepicture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:text="Save Image" />

</LinearLayout>
```